# Alternatives of document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, document.write

Is there an alternative way to write document.write() for this one?

```
  <b:widget id='HTML9' locked='true' title='Tab 1' type='HTML' version='1'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='content'>Test 1</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
        <div class='widget-content'>
          <script>//<![CDATA[
          var label1 = '<data:content/>';
          //]]>
          </script>
        </div>
      </b:includable>
  </b:widget>
  <b:widget id='HTML10' locked='true' title='Tab 2' type='HTML' version='1'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='content'>Test 2</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
        <div class='widget-content'>
          <script>//<![CDATA[
          var label2 = '<data:content/>';
          //]]>
          </script>
        </div>
      </b:includable>
```

This is what I'm using to call them:

```
<li class='tab-link' data-tab='tab-2'><a><script>document.write(label1);</script></a></li>
<li class='tab-link' data-tab='tab-3'><a><script>document.write(label2);</script></a></li>
```

`Test 1` and `Test2` are the names of Labels.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, create a container element with a unique id.

Then select the element by its id and add your content to it.

See this example

```html
<script> var label1 = "label Name"; </script>

<div id='tab-1'></div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('tab-1').innerHTML = label1;
</script>
```